# Prevent iOS lock screen when audio playing in Kik browser

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, jplayer, kik

I have an audio player that opens within the Kik browser. However, if I have my iOS lock screen set to lock after 2 minutes of inactivity, the lock screen will come up and stop the audio playback that was occurring within the Kik browser after 2 minutes. To restart audio playback I have to then unlock the screen, and then the audio will play for another 2 minute segment.

Is there any way to prevent the iOS lock screen from coming up while audio is playing within the Kik browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this meta tag to your HTML:

`<meta name="kik-media-enabled" content="true"/>`